# Converting column of dates/times to different timezone

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm a python newbie and I'm attempting to convert a column of combined dates and times to a different timezone using Pandas and Pytz (although I'm not married to Pytz). My data, called "data01," looks like this:

```
Activity Date
2016-10-25T00:40:56Z
2016-12-12T16:45:35Z
```

I'm able to convert those times individually copy/pasting using pytz, but when I'm trying to convert the entire column it errors out. I presume I need to localize it to UTC and then convert it to the desired timezone.

I've tried things like:

```
import timezone from pytz
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime 

raw_data01['Activity Date'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_data['Mycol'], format = '%Y:%m:%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Amongst others. I did my code at work and can't recall the 17 different errors nor copy paste it

Comment: do you want to convert all rows to the same TZ?

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39646898/5741205)?

Comment: This question could greatly be improved with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/7311767)