# Python - pandas datetime column with multiple timezones

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have a data frame with multiple users and timezones, like such:

```
cols = ['user', 'zone_name', 'utc_datetime']
data = [
    [1, 'Europe/Amsterdam', pd.to_datetime('2019-11-13 11:14:15')],
    [2, 'Europe/London', pd.to_datetime('2019-11-13 11:14:15')],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39648301/9153261) other post, I apply the following change to get the user local datetime:

```
df['local_datetime'] = df.groupby('zone_name')[
    'utc_datetime'
].transform(lambda x: x.dt.tz_localize(x.name))
```

Which outputs this:

```
    user    zone_name     utc_datetime          local_datetime
    1   Europe/Amsterdam  2019-11-13 11:14:15   2019-11-13 11:14:15+01:00
    2   Europe/London     2019-11-13 11:14:15   2019-11-13 11:14:15+00:00
```

However, the `local_datetime` column is an `object` and I cannot find a way to get it as `datetime64[ns]` and in the following format (desired output):

```
    user    zone_name     utc_datetime          local_datetime
    1   Europe/Amsterdam  2019-11-13 11:14:15   2019-11-13 12:14:15
    2   Europe/London     2019-11-13 11:14:15   2019-11-13 11:14:15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.dt.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) in lambda function:

```
df['local_datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.groupby('zone_name')['utc_datetime']
    .transform(lambda x: x.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert(x.name))
    .astype(str).str[:-6]))

print(df)
   user         zone_name        utc_datetime      local_datetime
0     1  Europe/Amsterdam 2019-11-13 11:14:15 2019-11-13 12:14:15
1     2     Europe/London 2019-11-13 11:14:15 2019-11-13 11:14:15
```

Comment: The data type is correct now :), but it should add 1 hour to the Amsterdam timezone not substract it.

Comment: @prp - hmmm, I am not expert for timezones, but it seems output is correct, if positive number after dates in utc are subtract values, if negative then are added values, check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) - last 2 samples to end of page

Comment: Amsterdam is +1 hour than London, but you can fix this by changing the arguments. I'll edit your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Relatively shorter answer using [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply):

```py
df['local_datetime'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.utc_datetime.tz_localize(tz = "UTC").tz_convert(x.zone_name), axis = 1)
print(df)
   user         zone_name        utc_datetime             local_datetime
0     1  Europe/Amsterdam 2019-11-13 11:14:15  2019-11-13 12:14:15+01:00
1     2     Europe/London 2019-11-13 11:14:15  2019-11-13 11:14:15+00:00
```

If you want to remove the time zone information, you can localize times by passing None

```py
df['local_datetime'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.utc_datetime.tz_localize(tz = "UTC").tz_convert(x.zone_name).tz_localize(None), axis = 1)
print(df)
   user         zone_name        utc_datetime      local_datetime
0     1  Europe/Amsterdam 2019-11-13 11:14:15 2019-11-13 12:14:15
1     2     Europe/London 2019-11-13 11:14:15 2019-11-13 11:14:15
```